# SVG element doesn't appear in IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a trouble with IE, of course. The SVG element doesn't appear in browser. Can someone help me?

This is my code

```
svg(preservAspectRatio='none', length='rem(250px)', height='1px', viewbox='0 0 250 1', version='1.1', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
    defs
    g#Page-1(stroke='none', stroke-width='1', fill='none', fill-rule='evenodd', opacity='0.400000006', stroke-dasharray='10,10', stroke-linecap='square')
        g#Pre-Order(transform='translate(-505.000000, -1162.000000)', stroke='#7A8EA5')
            g#Group-6(transform='translate(475.000000, 1135.000000)')
                path#Line(d='M30.5,27.5 L949.606631,27.5')`
```

Comment: I believe IE11 needs both the width and height to be set, but I could be wrong. I'm not familiar with that style of markup, but is `length` valid? Or is that supposed to be `width`? Also, the `height` is set to `1px`, is that correct? You will only see a 1px x 250px image?

Comment: This is not valid SVG. Whatever template language this is should be added as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Can be used is pure  `SVG`?
Rewrote the code according to the SVG syntax rules.
The application works in all browsers.

```html
<svg width="250" height="1", viewbox='0 0 250 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
   
    <g id="Page-1" stroke='none' stroke-width='1', fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' opacity='0.4', stroke-dasharray='10,10' stroke-linecap='square'>
        <g id="Pre-Order" transform='translate(-505.000000, -1162.000000)' stroke='#7A8EA5')>
            <g id="Group-6" transform='translate(475.000000, 1135.000000)'>
                <path id="#Line" d='M30.5,27.5 L949.606631,27.5'> </path>  
            </g>
            </g>
            </g>
                </svg>
```

if I understand correctly that you want to get something here is a shorter code:

```html
<svg width="250" height="1", viewbox='0 0 250 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'> 
    
    <g id="Page-1" stroke='black' stroke-width='1', fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' opacity='0.4',    stroke-dasharray='10,10' stroke-linecap='square'>
               <path id="#Line" d='M0 1 L250 1'> </path>  
     </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: @paveldub If the answer was useful to you, please do not forget to check it (check mark next to the answer number)